# MySQL only shows some data that is inserted by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-5.7

I have a Java application that loads data from a very large text file into MySQL via Hibernate. So far, the application seems to work OK - the data gets loaded.

Then I wanted to monitor the progress of the application while it was inserting data, so I wrote a small command-line utility that basically queries `select count(*) from my_table;`.

The first time this query is run (from either the CLI or MySQL Workbench), I get the correct number of records, as expected. All subsequent executions of this query *return the exact same number!* Even though the data-loading application is still running!

If I stop and start the MySQL process, querying for the number of records shows the *correct* number, as the data-loading application would report it.

I've never seen anything like this before. It looks like there is some strange MySQL caching issue going on here, and I'm concerned it may cause problems for other non-Hibernate applications that may want to access this database.

Does anyone know how to tweak MySQL (or possibly Hibernate) so that MySQL *always* shows what's being added to the database?

Technical details:

- MySQL: 5.7.26, in a docker container, using InnoDB storage
- Hibernate version: 5.4.2.Final
- Spring version: 5.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: MySQL won't show you anything that hasn't been committed by the transaction running the import. That's the I in ACID: Isolation between transactions.

Comment: I'm letting the frameworks manage transactions by annotating the method that is persisting data with the `@Transactional` (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) annotation. I thought that methods annotated with `@Transactional` would commit at the end of the method, and this method should insert 1 row. So I expected to be able to see the new data as it was being inserted.

Comment: Calling `FLUSH TABLES` seems to resolve this, in the sense that after I flush the tables, I can see how many records have been added by the application. I'm just not sure why I need to explicitly flush the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `FLUSH TABLES` seems to resolve this, in the sense that after I flush the tables, I can see how many records have been added by the application.